# How can i call a navigation "on press" in the <Flatlist>?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I using the flatlist to display a list of data. I wish to pass the data into another pages, but i have no idea to do it. This is my project, https://snack.expo.dev/@ryankurniantara/navigator-flatlist , Here i show you some of my code , the full code is in my snack expo above :

[image]

[image]

[image: This is the result i want to passing data through that button into the detail screen]

[image: An the result will show here]

Thanks For Your Help, your help will be very helpfull to me..

Comment: you can't use onPress function under the FlatList tag, You can use it with in render items but in your case you use onPress function on text tag which is not correct add onPress function on TouchableOpacity. because onPress is the function of TouchableOpacity.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, Its working fine

```
import React from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native'
import axios from 'axios'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {FlatList} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'

const index = ({navigation}) => {
  const [users,
    setUsers] = useState([]);

    const [curentPage,setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

const getUser = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios
        .get('https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/posts?page=' + curentPage)
        .then(res => {
            // setUsers(res.data.data);
            setUsers([...users,...res.data.data])
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
};

const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Id :{item.id}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>User Id :{item.user_id}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Tittle :{item.title}
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.container1}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.text} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detail')}>
                    <Text style={styles.tombol} >More Detail</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.line}></View>
        </View>
    )
};

const renderLoader = () => {
    return (
        isLoading ?
        <View style={styles.loaderstyle}>
            <ActivityIndicator size={'large'} color={"#aaa"}/>
        </View> : null
    )
}

const loadMoreItem = () => {
    setCurrentPage(curentage + 1);
}


useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
}, [curentPage])

return (  
    <>
    <FlatList
    data={users}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    ListFooterComponent={renderLoader}
    onEndReached={loadMoreItem}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0}/>
    </>
)
}

export default index

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 15
  },
  container1: {
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  text: {
    color: "black",
    marginTop: 5,
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: 'Arial'
},
line: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    marginVertical: 20
},
title: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: "black"
},
tombol: {
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'black',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: '100%'
},
loaderstyle: {
    marginVertical: 16,
    alignItems: 'center' 
}
})
```